# System.UnauthroizedAccessException: Access to path is denied when deploying .NET MAUI app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui

I'm having an issue where the first time I run my code in visual studio it will work fine. But when I go to run it again with no changes made access to the net8.0-android_Microsoft.Android.Resource.Designer.dll is denied and I'm also getting the error

> CS2012 Cannot open
> 'C:\Users\Tamzin\OneDrive\Documents\6002CEMMobileApp\Coursework\Coursework\Coursework\obj\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\intermediatexaml\Coursework.dll'
> for writing -- 'The requested operation cannot be performed on a file
> with a user-mapped section open.Coursework (net8.0-android).

I know this means that Visual studio doesnt have permission to open this file, but it will work once and then not again. I'm unsure as to why this is, sometimes this issue doesnt occur when I first start up visual studio and run my code but will then turn up later.
I've tried manually goint through my files and making sure theyre all set to read/write for all users, updating visual studio, trying different emulators, copying my code to a different location on my computer but nothing is working.
I think this is an issue where Visual Studio is kind of denying itself access and possible changing permissions?

Comment: Did you add the permission for the Android? You can check this answer about [MAUI :System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73221292/maui-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that is not permission problem. This comes up when another process is accessing your file so if VS is not the problem maybe your Antivirus. And if that does not help try to delete the build folder manuell before running your code or change the build output folder. Also a solution could be is running your VS with admin permissions.